# Doctrine2 security

Tags: doctrine-orm, sql-injection

I write server application in Symfony2 framework using Doctrine2 ORM. Now I need to secure my database from SQL injection. I read about this a little bit and I know that doctrine2 prepared statements can prevent my app from SQL injection attack. But is this secure me in 100%? Is there really no possibility to attack my server app? If there is any way, how can I defence from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you keep using Doctrine everywhere, all your statements will be secured via Doctrine.
I think noone can answer with: "There is a 100% security".

But when there is a known security issue which relates to Doctrine I am pretty sure it will be fixed soon, because there are many users working with it and many developers contributing to it.